# statsmodels mixed model takes a very long time

Tags: pandas, statsmodels, mixed-models

I have been trying to fit a mixed model using statsmodels, eg:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
model = smf.mixedlm('Y ~ cov_1 + cov_2 + cov_3', 
        data, 
        groups = data['grouping_variable']).fit()
```

where data is a pandas DataFrame. I have ~10,000 groups. For most subsets of my data, this works fine (it takes about 2 minutes to fit) but occasionally it hangs and runs for hours + without producing a result. I don't know why this might be or how to debug it.

Comment: Please note that the `mixedlm` model **does not** handle missing values, so please be sure to drop any missing values before calling this method.

Comment: hm interesting. It doesn't handle them even if you call it through the formula interface?

Comment: regardless, I don't think that's the problem; there is no missing data.